# WMI filter is ignored by certain clients in group policies

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, wmi

The applied WMI filter to a group policy  is ignored by certain clients.
It works fine on other clients, returns the correct value, but on some clients it is just not applied and does not appear in group policy results.

**Group Policy:**

- Computer Settings: Set WSUS configuration
- User Settings: [empty]

**WMI Filter:**
“Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem where Caption = …”

**Group Policy Results Wizard:**
Computer Configuration:

- Case 1: WMI filter is ignored by some clients, the policy is applied nevertheless
- Case 2: WMI filter is applied correctly and policy will only be applied to the correct clients (as it is defined in the wmi filter)

User Configuration:

Policy is applied regardless of the WMI filter, but that is no problem since the user configuration is empty

What is the best way to determine why some of the clients are ignoring the WMI filter?

**Edit**
Wmi is tested and working on all machines. The seems to that the group policy dosn't start the query on the remote machine, and not that the query is started and not working.

Comment: Can you include an actual WMI filter that is not working, instead of what you have here?

Comment: @GregAskew yes, but it will take some days. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

WMI is always fun to troubleshoot. It's a good idea to start by testing the query on those computers which aren't behaving properly. Run `wbemtest`, click connect, click connect, and the use the `Query` function to bring up a window where you can enter your WMI filter.

A simple example query is `Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem`, which should return `*Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="[YOURCOMPUTERNAME]*"`. For a basic WMI filter, a query that returns any number of objects is interpreted as true, while one that returns no objects is interpreted as false.

[image: Windows wbemtest]

Comment: Thanks, but not working WMI isn't the problem we see here. See edit